# How to access query variables in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, query-string

I want to access query string variable in **"single.php"** page which are assigned in **"archive.php"** page using these two functions

```
<?php set_query_var('name',value); // in archive.php page ?>
<?php $name = get_query_var('name'); //in single.php page ?>
```

This variable is accessible in **"archive.php"** page only not in **"single.php"** . How can i achieve this without using directly passing variable from url method ?

Comment: How @AniketSahrawat ? Could you explain it to me.

Comment: But custom functions are only accessible from functions.php not archive.php @AniketSahrawat ?

Comment: But then variable value will be lost . This value only work when a user click randomly on any link

Comment: Dude put your ego back and focus on what am i asking . If i have a variable that may contain anyone from multiple values depending upon user action . then hes redirected to single.php and you are saying to  include archive.php in single.php then the previous variable value that we get from user action will not be there as we have refreshed the page ?

Comment: Dude you must understand the question first dont try to misguide others.Is this the way how you earned points ?